# ListView not updating on button click when keyboard is hidden

Tags: android, android-listview, android-softkeyboard

I'm new to android development. I have an `EditText`, a `Button` and a `ListView`. When I click the button I want the string value to be added to the `ListView`. I have this working great.

However If I do this in the following order I get strange results with the UI. If I type some text, hide the keyboard by clicking back on the phone, then click the button, the `ListView` is not updated with the new item. The item has been added to the datasource (`List<String>`) because If I add another item again without hiding the keyboard the item I entered the previous time appears along with the newest one.

This is my code when the button is clicked.

```
public void AddName(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddName);
    list.add(editText.getText().toString());
    editText.setText("");
    hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this, view);
}
//This takes focus away from the EditText and hides the keyboard.
public static void hideSoftKeyboard (Activity activity, View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Here is where I fill the `ListView`. Note `GetList()` just returns `list` with default values in it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNames);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GetList());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    list.remove(item);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post your Adapter and the code when you update your ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have You tried add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to the end of AddName method?

If still don't work try to replace list.add with adapter.add

Comment: to do this I'll have to declare `adapter` at class level rather than in `onCreate`?